# How to access the fields from other models in Django

Tags: django, django-models, django-rest-framework, django-views

I am trying to make a application where the data incoming is in this format

{
"author name": "J. K. Rowling",
"books" : ["Harry potter 1" , "Harry potter 2"]
}

Now i made the models for author and books in the following format

```
class Author(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)


class Book(models.Model):
    name = models.ForeignKey(Author,on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    title = models.CharField(max_length=200)
```

The seralizers are :-

```
class BookSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Book
        fields = '__all__'

class AuthorSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    books = BookSerializer(many=True, required=False)  # Use the BookSerializer here

    class Meta:
        model = Author
        fields = '__all__'
```

Views are:

```
class AuthorViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    queryset = Author.objects.all()
    serializer_class = AuthorSerializer

class BookViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    queryset = Book.objects.all()
    serializer_class = BookSerializer
```

Custom View:-

```
class ImportDataViewSet(ViewSet):

    @action(methods=["POST"],detail=False)
    def import_data(self,request):
        data = request.data
        print(data)

        # deseralize the data and check
        book_seralizer = [BookSerializer(data = book_data) for book_data in data.get("books",[])]
        author_seralizer = AuthorSerializer(data = data.get("author"))
        if(author_seralizer.is_valid() and all(seralizer.is_valid() for seralizer in book_seralizer)):
            author_instance = author_seralizer.save()
            for book_instance in book_seralizer:
                book_instance.validated_data['author'] = author_instance
                print("hello ",book_instance.data)
                book_instance.save()
            
            return Response({"message","Data imported successfully"},status=200)
        else:
            author_errors = author_seralizer.errors if (author_seralizer.is_valid() == False) else {}
            book_errors = [serializer.errors for serializer in book_seralizer if(serializer.is_valid() == False)]
            errors = {
                "author_errors": author_errors,
                "book_errors": book_errors
            }

            return Response(errors,status=400)
```

URLS:-

```
router = DefaultRouter()
router.register(r"authors",AuthorViewSet)
router.register(r"books",BookViewSet)

import_data_view = ImportDataViewSet.as_view({"post":"import_data"})

urlpatterns = [
    path("",include(router.urls)),
    path("import_data/",import_data_view,name="import-data"),
]
```

Now when i post a request in this format i get an error in the book_errors as "Author name required"

Please help me with this

I tried to make a custom view like in the above code but it is not working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your custom view, you're trying to validate and save an Author instance and related Book instances. However, you're treating the AuthorSerializer and the list of BookSerializer instances differently, which could be causing the error.
To fix this, you should treat both the AuthorSerializer and the list of BookSerializer instances the same way by using the .save() method to create instances.

updated solution:-

```
class ImportDataViewSet(ViewSet):

    @action(methods=["POST"], detail=False)
    def import_data(self, request):
        data = request.data

        # Deserialize the data and check
        author_serializer = AuthorSerializer(data=data.get("author"))
        book_serializers = [BookSerializer(data=book_data) for book_data in data.get("books", [])]

        if author_serializer.is_valid() and all(serializer.is_valid() for serializer in book_serializers):
            author_instance = author_serializer.save()

            for book_serializer in book_serializers:
                book_serializer.validated_data['name'] = author_instance.id  # Set the author ID
                book_instance = book_serializer.save()

            return Response({"message": "Data imported successfully"}, status=200)
        else:
            author_errors = author_serializer.errors if not author_serializer.is_valid() else {}
            book_errors = [serializer.errors for serializer in book_serializers if not serializer.is_valid()]
            errors = {
                "author_errors": author_errors,
                "book_errors": book_errors
            }

            return Response(errors, status=400)
```